# Не попадаю в callback после успешной оплаты LiqPay

Tags: node.js, liqpay

После успешной оплаты через LiqPay, ссылка оплаты формируется через POST (https://www.liqpay.ua/api/3/checkout) не идёт в указанный server_url.

Объект параметров:

```
const params = {
    action: action,
    amount: amount,
    currency: currency,
    description: description,
    public_key: process.env.LIQPAY_PUBLIC_KEY,
    private_key: process.env.LIQPAY_PRIVATE_KEY,
    server_url: 'http://localhost:6789/payment/callback',
}
```

В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: если запрос отправляется системой liqpay (с серверов liqpay), а не конечным клиентом, то liqpay не может отправить на ваш localhost, т.к. localhost всегда указывает на локальную машину, т.е. сервера liqpay, возможно нужно разместить ваше приложение где-то и получить реальный домен